# Ml.Net Imageclassification incremental learning

Tags: machine-learning, ml.net, image-classification

Is Ml.net image classification trainer support incremental learning or not and if yes can anybody show me example or topic to read it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by incremental learning you're referring to taking the weights from a trained model and using that as the starting point to continue training, it's not supported at the moment. Technically though you're not starting from scratch with the image classification trainer since you're using transfer learning to train the last layer of the chosen pretrained image classification network, but incremental learning on your trained model is currently not supported. I would suggest posting an issue in the repo requesting this feature so others who may want this feature as well are able to upvote / comment on it.

https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/new/choose